# Editing wp-config.php from external plugin

Tags: wordpress, ssl, plugins

I need a way to access to the **wp-config.php** file in **Wordpress**, and add some values.

To be straight, I want to add this current values.

```
define('FORCE_SSL_LOGIN', true);
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
```

But I want to add them from my plugin. Are there any default Wordpress functions, or something else for doing this.

Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The plugin [Quick Cache](http://wordpress.org/plugins/quick-cache/) adds `define('WP_CACHE', true);` when activated and removes it on deactivation. Here's a simplified version of how it works.

On activation, it replaces `<?php` with its code `<?php define(etc)`:

```
function wp_config_put( $slash = '' ) {
    $config = file_get_contents (ABSPATH . "wp-config.php");
    $config = preg_replace ("/^([\r\n\t ]*)(\<\?)(php)?/i", "<?php define('WP_CACHE', true);", $config);
    file_put_contents (ABSPATH . $slash . "wp-config.php", $config);
}

if ( file_exists (ABSPATH . "wp-config.php") && is_writable (ABSPATH . "wp-config.php") ){
    wp_config_put();
}
else if (file_exists (dirname (ABSPATH) . "/wp-config.php") && is_writable (dirname (ABSPATH) . "/wp-config.php")){
    wp_config_put('/');
}
else { 
    add_warning('Error adding');
}
```

On deactivation, it searches for its code using a pattern that does not includes `<?php` (if I'm understanding it correctly) and removes it:

```
function wp_config_delete( $slash = '' ) {
    $config = file_get_contents (ABSPATH . "wp-config.php");
    $config = preg_replace ("/( ?)(define)( ?)(\()( ?)(['\"])WP_CACHE(['\"])( ?)(,)( ?)(0|1|true|false)( ?)(\))( ?);/i", "", $config);
    file_put_contents (ABSPATH . $slash . "wp-config.php", $config);
}

if (file_exists (ABSPATH . "wp-config.php") && is_writable (ABSPATH . "wp-config.php")) {
    wp_config_delete();
}
else if (file_exists (dirname (ABSPATH) . "/wp-config.php") && is_writable (dirname (ABSPATH) . "/wp-config.php")) {
    wp_config_delete('/');
}
else if (file_exists (ABSPATH . "wp-config.php") && !is_writable (ABSPATH . "wp-config.php")) {
    add_warning('Error removing');
}
else if (file_exists (dirname (ABSPATH) . "/wp-config.php") && !is_writable (dirname (ABSPATH) . "/wp-config.php")) {
    add_warning('Error removing');
}
else {
    add_warning('Error removing');
}
```